# optimising reading id3 tags of mp3 files

Tags: ruby, file, optimization, mp3

I'm trying to read mp3 files using 'mp3info' gem and by going through each file which ends with .mp3 in its file name in a directory and going inside a directory using Dir.chdir() and repeating the process and storing these tags in database. But I have 30gb of music collection and it takes around 6-10 mins for the whole scan to complete. Is there any way I can optimise this scan?

```
        def self.gen_list(dir)
        prev_pwd=Dir.pwd
        begin
            Dir.chdir(dir)
        rescue Errno::EACCES
        end
        counter = 0
        Dir[Dir.pwd+'/*'].each{|x|
            #puts Dir.pwd
            if File.directory?(x) then
                self.gen_list(x) do |y|
                    yield y
                end
            else if File.basename(x).match('.mp3') then
                    begin
                        Mp3Info.open(x) do |y|
                            yield [x,y.tag.title,y.tag.album,y.tag.artist]
                        end
                    rescue Mp3InfoError
                    end
                end  
            end
        }
        Dir.chdir(prev_pwd)
    end
```

This is the method which generates list and sends the tags to &block where data is stored in database..

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: I thought code would not be much useful, updated the question with some code.. thanks

Comment: As a side note, there is a bug in this Gem and from what I understand it's not supported anymore. Some MP3 are generated using an older version of iTune which sticks 2 extra bytes in some of the ID3 frames and as a result the size of those ID3 frames is wrong. The Mp3Info gem doesn't handle that case properly. And yes even in 2020 we still see some MP3 files generated with those invalid tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the parse_mp3 flag to false? by default it is on which means you are going to pull in the entire file for each scan when all you care about is the info. I don't know how much time this will save you. See the github source for more info.

https://github.com/moumar/ruby-mp3info/blob/master/lib/mp3info.rb#L214

```
# Specify :parse_mp3 => false to disable processing of the mp3
def initialize(filename_or_io, options = {})
```

Comment: it saved like 4 mins, othes answers are also valid, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Run several processes (for each directory in the base dir, for example)
2. Use threads with rubinius or JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby) gem which is unlike mp3info wrapper over C library and it could give you little bit more performance. Otherwise you have to stick to JRuby and run multiple threads (4 if you have 4 cores).

Answer (score 0):

You may also benefit from a more direct way of retrieving the mp3 files.

```
Dir['**/*.mp3'].each |filepath|
  Mp3Info.open(filepath) do |mp3|
    ...
  end
rescue Mp3ErrorInfo
  ...
end
```

This will find all .mp3 files at any depth from the current directory and yield the relative path to the block. It is approximately equivalent to `find . -name '*.mp3' -print`